# nginx rule for two locations for files in one directory

Tags: nginx, location, webserver, rule

I have the following directory:

```
]# ls /srv/web/logs/
yellow-log  blue-log  log.css
```

I want to have two links:

- `example.com/yellow-log`
- `example.com/blue-log`

What should the nginx rule look like for this? I've tried:

```
location ~* ^/(?:yellow|blue)-log(?:/|.html)?$ {
    alias /srv/web/logs;
}
```

but that complains about missing index. I simply want each of those pages to be served when a request is made for them, and both should reside in the same directory. Both use the same `log.css` file.

Comment: `alias` should probably be `root`. But I don't understand what file type your "log" files are or how you intend to serve up the CSS file.

Comment: @RichardSmith the log files are regular HTML files and both link to the CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have half the solution. Problem is you use `alias` when you mean `root` and you have no path to the CSS file. Assuming the CSS file is relative to the HTML file, it's URI will actually be `example.com/log.css`. The log files have no extension and therefore require a `default_type`.

One solution is:

```
location ~* ^/(?:yellow|blue)-log$ {
  default_type text/html;
  root /srv/web/logs;
}
location = log.css { root /srv/web/logs; }
```

Comment: A ha, the default_type option is something I didn't know about. Thanks! Though, if I use the config you provided, the requests are still resulting in 404s because a request for `example.com/yellow-log` produces this error in the log file: `"/srv/web/logs/yellow-log/index.html" is not found`

Comment: @mart1n That's probably elsewhere in your config file (or perhaps the browser). But something is rewriting `example.com/yellow-log` to `example.com/yellow-log/`. I didn't see that in my test environment.

Comment: Ha, you're right again. I added a rule to remove trailing slashes from all requests and it works now: `rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;`. Thank you!